# java sql random row print

Tags: java, database, wamp

i try to print random row but i could not   , how can i print random row?

-data base name test
 -table name user_data

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class sqlconnect {
public static void main(String args[]) {
try {

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root",""); 
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from user_data ORDER BY RANDOM() OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROW ONLY");

while(rs.next())

System.out.println(rs.getString(1)); 
con.close();
} 
catch (Exception e){ System.out.println(e);} 
}
}
```

i try this code this is the error message

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROW ONLY' at line 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to just print a random row then use `LIMIT 1` to tell MySQL to limit the result set to one record:

```
SELECT * FROM user_data ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

**Code:**

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM user_data ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
```

Your use of `FETCH NEXT` appears to be SQL Server syntax (q.v. [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618(v=sql.110).aspx)).

Comment: I think it should be `RAND()` and not `RANDOM()` in MySQL.

Comment: @Beginner You leave me wondering who the beginner actually is here :-)

Comment: build successful but its print this error  **com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: FUNCTION test.RANDOM does not exist**

Comment: yep sure and how can i know which row is printed ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149774/discussion-between-sanjan-and-tim-biegeleisen).

Comment: @sanjan You can perhaps check some of the fields that come back when you do `SELECT *` to figure out which record you have.